# Liferay's URL field not getting indexed in Solr

Tags: solr, liferay

Has anyone been able to get the liferay url's indexed in solr? (By url I simply mean the liferay page on which portlet/s may be hosted.)

Although the field is defined in the schema, I don't see the values in a solr query response!
In fact, the url field is never returned in the response.

Any suggestions? (Our portlet will be hitting the solr server directly to fetch results)

I tried with url as text, indexed=true and stored=true and
string, indexed=true and stored=true

Answer (score 0):

In Liferay pages/urls cosntructed by the Layout object. As far as I know, I dont see the Layout object is being indexed in the first place.

If you want to index the layout object, you may consider writing a hook. At the time of Adding/Updating a layout you can create an index on the layout object.

For example: you can refer to the BookMarks portlet, there you can see how to index bookmarks.

```
Indexer indexer = IndexerRegistryUtil.getIndexer(
BookmarksEntry.class);
indexer.reindex(entry);
```

[click here](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Adding+search+capabilities+to+a+portlet)

To see how to add custom search capabilities.

Comment: Ok, so any idea what this particular URL field is supposed to contain?

Comment: I think you are referring to the SOLR url field. Which is different from Liferay page URL. every solr index will have this URL field irrespective of Liferay.

Comment: I checked the Indexer.java class for Bookmarks, Wiki etc. I see that the page URL is getting indexed as Field.url itself. So the URL is definitely going somewhere? (indexes?)

Comment: Can you also check by creating a Wiki or a Bookmark and then see what could go into that URL field of a SOLR index? If the liferay page url is being stored, then you may have to go for that option (Providing custom search capabilities to portlets.)

Answer (score 0):

Pages or Menu structure are not indexed automatically in Liferay.

A simple workaround without Programming:

- Create a WebContent for each Page that you want to index. Webcontent Name and Content shall contain the page name
- Make sure that WebContent Display Page is NOT set.
- Add the WebContent to the page (at the bottom)
- Change the Color for the WebContent Text to the Background Color (make it invisible) in Look&Feel Menu
- Make sure that the search portlet is configured to "Display in Context"
- Search the Page Name aka WebContent Name. Your entry will be on top of the search result. If Not set the Ranking of the WebContent higher...